# Detect required disk space for ExoPlayer offline download

Tags: android, exoplayer, offline-caching, exoplayer2.x

ExoPlayer has nice features for downloading video for later offline use. It also provides CacheEvictor for selecting behaviour when the disk space is getting low. However, I would like to provide user possibility to clean up some space before even starting the download, or a chance to choose poorer quality for less space consumption.

Since we are talking about adaptive streams, not single mp4 files, learning the needed disk space seems not to be trivial. I am fine with a reasonably accurate estimate, but I can't come up even with that. Naturally it has to be available after user has selected the bitrate(s) to be downloaded and before the actual download. `Download` class has `contentLength` variable, but it seem to be zero (on adaptive streams?). `DownloadRequest` has `streamKeys` as indices to selected  streams, but I have not found any place where I could use those. From our own metadata I can find out the length of the stream in seconds, so I guess there are three alternatives I am looking for:

- a way to get estimated bytes for the starting download,
- a way to get selected bitrates of all the streams related to selected streamKeys or
- a way to get ExoPlayer itself not to start the download if there is not enough space

from which I assume the middle one is the most likely to be available. Any ideas or knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I pointed out in the question, with the length and the bitrate it is possible to calculate reasonable estimate. Getting length should be trivial and may be implementation specific, for getting selected bitrate (or help for selecting the bitrate) following classes and method calls will be useful (parameters and details excluded):

```
DownloadHelper.getMappedTrackInfo().getRenderedType() 
DownloadHelper.getMappedTrackInfo().getRenderedType() 
DownloadHelper.getMappedTrackInfo().getTrackGroups().get().getFormat().bitrate
```